# PyQT4: getting text from Ui for existing python program

Tags: python, user-interface, text, pyqt4, qt-creator

I'm trying to create a UI for an existing python program that I've made. 
On the widget, I have two text boxes (QlineEdit) that I want to use to get the information for the program to use, a button and a textbrowser that will hold the output of the program.

I've stumbled upon PyQT4, which I installed using homebrew, and QT Creator. I've created the UI and converted it from a mainwindow.ui to a mainwindow.py and now I'm trying to figure out how to get the text input from the UI text boxes and have the program use it.

I cant figure out how to extract the text from the text boxes(QlineEdit) and store them in variables(strings) that the program can then use.

From my understanding, I should create a new .py file and import mainwindow as well as PyQT4.QtCore and PyQT4.QtGui. I dont know where to go from here so any insight would be helpful.

Also, how can I have the program print out to the textbrowser?

Maybe my approach is flawed and I should rebuild my program around the mainwindow.py file?

I apologize if this is all trivial information but I've never used PyQT or Qt creator.

Here is the code that I got from the the converted .ui to .py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Aug 13 15:25:22 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(480, 385)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralWidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 256, 192))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 156, 97))
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textEdited(QString)")), self.lineEdit.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textEdited(QString)")), self.lineEdit_2.setText)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Case Number", None))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number of cases", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any information helps. Thanks

Comment: As a shameless plug, if you're looking to turn existing python scripts (effectively, command-line applications) into something with a UI then I've made an application that does exactly that: [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9yfpqWiyUg), [source](https://github.com/adamkewley/jobson). It creates a web server + web UI though, instead of a client application like Qt would. It might be a useful shortcut if you find you're writing wrapper UIs like this a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way UI works is that the UI forms the main loop of the program. Here mainwindow.py is your main loop. You can import your classes that you created in your program (lets call it code.py) or just paste that code into you mainwindow.py. Then on button press or some other kind of event, you can call a function that execute the **main** code of your code.py

To answer your other questions regarding how to use the text and print to the textbrowser try something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Aug 13 15:25:22 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
            return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(480, 385)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralWidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 256, 192))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 156, 97))
        self.widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("widget"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textEdited(QString)")), self.lineEdit.setText)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.lineEdit_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("textEdited(QString)")), self.lineEdit_2.setText)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Case Number", None))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number of cases", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit", None))

        # Call a function when the button "Submit" is pressed
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OnSubmit)


    def OnSubmit(self):

        # On submit do the necessary 
        # here I take the text from the LineEdits that you have 
        # (ie your Case Number, and number of Cases) 
        # and print them to the textbrowser below

        text = self.lineEdit.text() + ' ' + self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.textBrowser.append(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can find some basic tutorials here: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/ that can help you understand the properties of your QtGui objects.

Comment: This clears up a couple questions. However, when I try to implement the code you provided, I get an error:   `Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "mainwindow.py", line 97, in <module>  
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)  
  File "mainwindow.py", line 68, in setupUi  
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)  
  File "mainwindow.py", line 78, in retranslateUi  
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.OnSubmit)  
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'OnSubmit'`  What does that error mean? Can I fix it?

Comment: Since I refer to the function as self.OnSubmit in line 78, it has to be a function of the class Ui_MainWindow. So add OnSubmit as a function of the class and it should work. I edited the code in the answer with the complete code.